# Can't Add Profile To Contribution Page

Tags: profile, contribution-page

I get this error when I try to attach a profile for the SignUp Form.
I noticed also that in the Profile Tab of the Contribution the Civicrm Profiles are not displayed in a drop down. Instead what you have is a text form.

I am using Civicrm 4.6.8 with Wordpress4.4.2.

Comment: Did you look at the console?

Comment: It is very helpful if you can replicate your steps on the WP demo site and then provide links for others to check.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles that have fields from things other than contacts (and subtypes) and contributions can't be used on Contribution pages. Check to make sure you haven't included a core or custom field for a different type of object like an event registration, memebership, activity, etc. on the profile(s) you want to display on the contribution page.